# CSS3 parent's visibility: hover transition hides child's visibility:visible transition after a delay

Tags: html, css, visibility, transition, hidden

Providing an example jsfiddle below, I want to make a parent div invisible at the same time as a child div visible with a CSS3 hover transition. But when I do this, after the transition is over, the child div disappears.

When moving the mouse, still on the child div, it appears again, only to re-disappear after a few seconds.

Showing does more than explaining in words, so here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4LgG6/

In above example, the green semitransparent child div should appear while the yellow parent div should disappear when you hover on it. I made the green div semitransparent so you would see a darker blackish green, as the background is black; and not a yellow-ish green as the yellow parent is invisible.

It seems to work, partly, and only for a few seconds, before completely becoming black.
Moving your cursor on the hover lets the green become visible again, but only for a few seconds once again.

I tested it with Safari, Chrome and Opera, and all give problems.

Any help?

This is the html:

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="yellow">
         <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the css:

```
.bg {
    background: #111;
    height:200px;
}
.green {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
    opacity:0;
}
.yellow {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
 }
.yellow:hover .green {
    opacity:0.5;
}
.yellow:hover {
     visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're going for? http://jsfiddle.net/4LgG6/5/
Removed the .yellow:hover, added "ease" to transitions.

Removing the last .yellow:hover block is what resolves it, but leaves you with the plain green block as opposed to a darker one.

`.yellow:hover { visibility: hidden; }`

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4LgG6/6/

Simply added `visibility: visible;` to `.green`

Comment: Not really, as the yellow is still active, and with transparency on green, you can still see yellow. What I want is to see no yellow, only darker green, with the background come through.